# How to get Text of radio button instead of value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is the code generated by the software

```
<div id="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-month-or-course-radios" class="myzebra-radios">
  <div class="myzebra-radios-single">
    <label class="myzebra-style-label">
      <input id="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-month-or-course_wpcf-fields-radio-option-a6da15467aeb84f539c0dc1cd766ccd6-2" class="myzebra-control myzebra-radio myzebra-prime-name-wpcf-ticket-month-or-course" type="radio" checked="checked" value="wpcf-fields-radio-option-a6da15467aeb84f539c0dc1cd766ccd6-2" name="wpcf-ticket-month-or-course">
      <span class="myzebra-radio-replace"></span>
    </label>
    <label id="cred_form_3584_1_label_wpcf-ticket-month-or-course_wpcf-fields-radio-option-a6da15467aeb84f539c0dc1cd766ccd6-2" for="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-month-or-course_wpcf-fields-radio-option-a6da15467aeb84f539c0dc1cd766ccd6-2">per month</label>
  </div>
<div class="myzebra-radios-single">
  <label class="myzebra-style-label">
    <input id="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-month-or-course_wpcf-fields-radio-option-f63eb739e2a6499a882c8e82aa35b028-1" class="myzebra-control myzebra-radio myzebra-prime-name-wpcf-ticket-month-or-course" type="radio" value="wpcf-fields-radio-option-f63eb739e2a6499a882c8e82aa35b028-1" name="wpcf-ticket-month-or-course">
    <span class="myzebra-radio-replace"></span>
  </label>
  <label id="cred_form_3584_1_label_wpcf-ticket-month-or-course_wpcf-fields-radio-option-f63eb739e2a6499a882c8e82aa35b028-1" for="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-month-or-course_wpcf-fields-radio-option-f63eb739e2a6499a882c8e82aa35b028-1">per course</label>
</div>
```

Using this code:

```
alert($('input[@name="myzebra-radios-single"]:checked').text());
```

I get the value but not the text. How do I get the text (e.g per month) instead?

Comment: I would appreciate any answers that can do the same for other inputs like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfLfa/

Comment: Your example doesn't have an `input` with the name `myzebra-radios-single`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the contents of the `label`, you need to use its `for=` attribute:

```
var $input = $('input[name=something]:checked');
var text = $('label[for='+$input.attr('id')+']').text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/RDPP7/

Answer (score 0):

First of all the radio elements doesn't have any text values, if they did however.

```
alert($('input[@name="myzebra-radios-single"]:checked').text());
// Should be
alert($('input[@name="wpcf-ticket-month-or-course"]:checked').text());
```

When I breakdown your inputs they look something like this

```
<input 
    id="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-month-or-course_wpcf-fields-radio-option-f63eb739e2a6499a882c8e82aa35b028-1" 
    class="myzebra-control myzebra-radio myzebra-prime-name-wpcf-ticket-month-or-course" 
    type="radio" 
    value="wpcf-fields-radio-option-f63eb739e2a6499a882c8e82aa35b028-1" 
    name="wpcf-ticket-month-or-course">
```

If you want to pick a certain attribute from the above the use either .val() .text() or .attr().

Answer (score 0):

try :

`alert($('input[@name="myzebra-radios-single"]:checked').attr('name'));`